# rosbag2 - how to save bags in a place of my choice?

Tags: ros, ros2, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know how to use `rosbag2` (CLI, launch file, SequentialWriter) with option to choose where rosbag2 will be saved.

1. with CLI:

`ros2 bag record /chatter -o ~/rosbags_folder`

I can easily use the `-o` option there.

2. with launch file like this:

   from launch import LaunchDescription
   from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess

   def generate_launch_description():
   # recording all topics with `ros2 bag record`
   return LaunchDescription(
   [
   ExecuteProcess(
   cmd=["ros2", "bag", "record", "-a"],
   output="screen",
   )
   ]
   )

How should I change it so that's after the `-a` in `cmd` I can have `-o` with an argument given during launch, e.g.
`cmd = ["ros2", "bag", "record", "-a", "-o", MyAwesomePathSetThroughTerminal]`?
Or should I rather use YAML files with parameters like in this tutorial: https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-yaml-params/ for this?

3. With [this code](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Ros2bag/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-Python.html#write-the-python-node) from ROS Documentation (Recording a bag from your own node (Python))

   import rclpy
   from rclpy.node import Node
   from rclpy.serialization import serialize_message
   from std_msgs.msg import String

   import rosbag2_py

   class SimpleBagRecorder(Node):
   def **init**(self):
   super().**init**('simple_bag_recorder')
   self.writer = rosbag2_py.SequentialWriter()

   ```
        storage_options = rosbag2_py._storage.StorageOptions(
            uri='my_bag',
            storage_id='sqlite3')
        converter_options = rosbag2_py._storage.ConverterOptions('', '')
        self.writer.open(storage_options, converter_options)

        topic_info = rosbag2_py._storage.TopicMetadata(
            name='chatter',
            type='std_msgs/msg/String',
            serialization_format='cdr')
        self.writer.create_topic(topic_info)

        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            'chatter',
            self.topic_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription

    def topic_callback(self, msg):
        self.writer.write(
            'chatter',
            serialize_message(msg),
            self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds)
   ```

   def main(args=None):
   rclpy.init(args=args)
   sbr = SimpleBagRecorder()
   rclpy.spin(sbr)
   rclpy.shutdown()

   if **name** == '**main**':
   main()

Where can I change the default options inside SequentialWriter etc. so it change saving place from `./` to `some_global_or_local_PATH/` (path set in the outside code)? I can workaround it with setting `uri='my_bag'` to `uri='/some_PATH/my_bag'`, but it feels like cheating. Is there a better option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398163/rosbag2---how-to-save-bags-in-a-place-of-my-choice?/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-03-29**:
I think maybe some answer from this question could help: https://answers.ros.org/question/363763/ros2-how-best-to-conditionally-include-a-prefix-in-a-launchpy-file/ but I will look into it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have somewhat solved my problem with use of this hack:

```
ros2ws_dir = "/".join(get_package_share_directory('bag_recorder_pkg').split('/')[:-4]) 
# it gives e.g. /home/user/ros2_ws/
```

Then in the code of I give in `__init__` of SimpleBagRecorder `uri` equal to timestamp + `ros2ws_dir + "/rosbags/"`. It saves the bag in my `ros2_ws`in the folder `rosbags/`.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0